# Google Guice: Singleton with xml deserialization support?

Tags: singleton, guice, xml-deserialization

in my project I need a class which contains the project configuration.
The configuration must be loaded from a XML file and must be a singleton.

In Guice there is a singleton scope. Now I have to "overwrite" the singleton with the deserialized configuration.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: You should probably get rid of this XML file and move everything in it into a module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important: pelase do note that Guice was originally created to get rid of all these huge and ugly XML files used by another DI library for managing dependencies. In general, when using Guice, you should be able to -almost- completely remove any XML from your project.

But if you must, perhaps because the XML file is generated by something outside your control then consider these:

Keep your whole configuration object and create a `Provider` for it, and bind it in Singleton scope. But you'll have to perform deserialization by yourself.

Or if your configuration is simply made of (name, value) pairs, then you can use `java.util.Properties` whcih can be loaded from an XML file, then use Guice `Names.bindProperties()` API in one of your `Module`s.

Then you can directly inject each single property by using `@Inject @Named`.

Comment: Good answer; but I'm moving the important note up to the top.

Comment: But how can I get rid of XML files if I need to define some essential settings for my app and like to change them after compiling?

For example: port, some paths, etc.

Comment: For such simple settings, the usual properties file would do without any issue (except if it has to contain Unicode strings, whcih it doesn't support). The real question is: "who defines the exact format of the configuration fiel?"

Comment: You're right, a property file should be enough. I've prefered an XML file because I don't know exactly which addition settings I need in the future. Maybe I should think twice which configuration I need to store.